# Samba Displaying Folders as Files

Tags: ubuntu, samba, server-message-block, cifs

I have a Windows share (shared from a Windows Server 2003 box) that is mounted on our Ubuntu server using cifs. That mount is then shared out through Samba. The issue is that all of the folders in the share display as FILES. For example, imagine this folder structure:

```
>Share Level
>> FolderOne
>>> File
>> FolderTwo
>> FileOne
```

So, when I enter the root of the share from a Windows 7 machine, FolderOne, FolderTwo and FileOne all display as files. If I attempt to enter FolderOne by clicking on it's icon, it fails. If I go directly to the folder with a UNC path (\\server\share\FolderOne) I can enter the folder correctly.

Options on the CIFS mount: dirmode=0770, file_mode=0770, rw

Samba options on the share:

```
writeable = yes
printable = no
browseable = yes
force user = <primary file owner>
force group = <primary file group>
valid users = <needed access>
```

This is an Ubuntu 12.04.2 server running Samba 3.6.3.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the samba. Could you try without the
" dirmode=0770, file_mode=0770, rw " ?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of a question on ServerFault, and some help from kukk in the #samba IRC chatroom led to this information:

[Directories shown as files, when sharing a mounted cifs drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/491464/directories-shown-as-files-when-sharing-a-mounted-cifs-drive)

https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9346

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52791

Short answer, yes, it doesn't work correctly, and the only solution is to hack a bit at the CIFS source code and recompile.